# Reduce sum of digits recursively down to one digit number

Tags: java, recursion, methods

How do I make a function return the sum of all digits until it becomes a 1 digit number, using recursion?  I was able to make a function that gets the sum of all digits, but cant seem to find a way to recursively sum the digits of the sum itself:

```
class sum_of_digits 
{ 

    static int sum_of_digit(int n) 
    {  
        if (n == 0) 
            return 0; 
        return (n % 10 + sum_of_digit(n / 10)); 
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        int num = 12345; 
        int result = sum_of_digit(num); 
        System.out.println("Sum of digits in " +  
                           num + " is " + result); 
    } 
}
```

This code prints the sum of '12345', which is 15. But I need to change it so it prints the sum of 1 + 5, which is 6.

Comment: Create a method recursiveSumUntilOneDigitLeft(). Call it from main. In this method, call sum_of_digit(). If the result has more than one digit, call recursiveSumUntilOneDigitLeft() with the result.

Comment: @JBNizet It works, thanks.
do you think it is possible to make it work without an additional method?

Comment: Make sure to add a bounds check in case of negative values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> do you think it is possible to make it work without an additional
>   method?

Why can't we just let the recursion do the work for us and simply say:

```
static int sum_of_digit(int n) 
{  
    if (n < 10) 
        return n;

    return sum_of_digit(n % 10 + sum_of_digit(n / 10)); 
}
```

Comment: @TFT, there are two issues here.  First, your original comment implied a syntax error to me that doesn't exist -- what you're suggesting is a logic change.  Second, your understanding of the problem is incorrect.  Reread the OP's description, specifically, "until it becomes a 1 digit number, using recursion".

Comment: Ok I get it now, sorry for the misunderstanding lol! Anyway, thanks for explaning

Answer (score 3):

Things will become a lot easier if you define an additional recursive "layer" in conjunction with sum_of_digit. This new function can call sum_of_digit until it has a single digit as a result. Here is what I mean:

```
static int sum_to_one_digit(int n) {
    if(n/10 == 0) return n;
    return sum_to_one_digit(sum_of_digit(n));
}
```

The code from main will be:

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    int num = 12345; 
    int result = sum_to_one_digit(num); 
    System.out.println("Sum of digits in " +  
                   num + " is " + result); 
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks.
do you think it is possible to make it work without an additional method?

Comment: @Lior Nothing immediately pops out to me while keeping sum_of_digit recursive. Perhaps you could come up with a clever base case + recursive step. However, the easier way out would probably be to define the function iteratively.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a clause at the end to check whether the sum is smaller than 10, if it isn't then recursively call it again with the newly calculated sum, ie.

```
static int sum_of_digit(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    int temp = (n % 10 + sum_of_digit(n / 10));
    if (temp < 10)
        return temp;
    return sum_of_digit(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it, one would be like this if global variables are allowed :

```
public class Sum_of_digits{
        static int sum = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]){

        int n = 12345;
        System.out.println(sum_of_digit(n));
        sum = 0;

    }
    static int sum_of_digit(int n){

        if(n==0){
            if(sum/10 == 0){
                return sum;
            }else{
                n=sum;
                sum=0;
            }
        }
        sum = sum+(n%10);
        n=n/10;
        return sum_of_digit(n);

    }
}
```

and if Global variable are not allowed then passing sum as a parameter will help :

```
public class Sum_of_digits{


        public static void main(String args[]){

            int n = 12345;
            int sum = 0;
            System.out.println(sum_of_digit(n,sum));

        }
        static int sum_of_digit(int n,int sum){

            if(n==0){
                if(sum/10 == 0){
                    return sum;
                }else{
                    n=sum;
                    sum=0;
                }
            }
            sum = sum+(n%10);
            n=n/10;
            return sum_of_digit(n,sum);

        }
    }
```

Here we are just shifting the focus from **n** to **sum** to evaluate the condition when the loop/recursion will terminate.

Comment: For reader clarity, this response also addresses the follow up remark from @Lior asking if it is possible to do without an additional method.

Comment: I wouldn't advocate the use of a global sum variable. Repeated calls to sum_of_digit will have unexpected behavior since you are not clearing it.

Comment: Global modifiable variables are evil, don't use them, pass them as parameters or keep them local

Comment: agreed, modifying global variable has the tendency to create unexpected problems if not controlled properly. it should be reset at the end of the program or not to be used at all. Modifying the first example.